# S3 web hosting for backbone.js application with pushState

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I'm hosting a Backbone application on Amazon S3 using a custom domain name. The Backbone application router handles all routes under the root ('/'). I would like to use pushState, so there's no need for the # prefix on my application routes. Basically, i want all sub-routes to be routed by S3 to the domain root and let Backbone do the rest.

I added the following rule:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
    <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals >
     </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>mydomain.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

But this just adds the # sign prefix to all my sub-routes. I want to avoid that.

How do I set the redirection rules on my S3 bucket to route everything to the indexed document without having to add the #?

Answer (score 0):

You say "just adds the # sign" but what that does is actually load the index.html page. That is because `www.example.com/#my-folder/my-page/whatever` is actually loading `/index.html` and sending the browser the `#my-folder/my-page/whatever` as a fragment. You could do it if you ran the website on a server, but not in S3. You could use push-state once the page loads to read the fragment `#my-folder/my-page/whatever` and rewrite it to `my-folder/my-page/whatever`, and I believe that would achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: That is disappointing. I was hoping to avoid running my own web server for static content and rely entirely on S3 web-hosting features.